# What is the latest version of Groovy supporting JDK 1.4

Tags: java, groovy, jdk1.4

I need to run Groovy on an embedded 1.4-compatible VM. The current Groovy version requires at least JDK 1.5.

Some version in the past did support JDK 1.4, but the current version does not.

Comment: Body text detailing what research you've done so far would add value.

Comment: This question will be useless in X days.  Where X is a small number.

Comment: Why would my research add value? I don't know the answer, and someone here might.

Comment: Why will this question age? It is unlikely that any future versions of Groovy will support JDK 1.4, so whatever version currently supports it is likely to be the answer forever.

Comment: Really, 4 votes to close a question that has real value and hasn't been asked before, just because I didn't tell you what research I've done so far?

Comment: Closed on what grounds please? Not small geographic area, applicable from now until eternity and not extraordinarily narrow. I'm a good citizen here and this was an honest question.

Comment: Perhaps those downvoting closing this may want to consider embedding and test scenario's where the JVM version is not flexible - in which case this is a perfect valid scenario. Considering that embedded devices (including phones, TV's, STB's and the like) are outnumbering desktop/server types - this is far from too localized. As for "a moment in time" - these devices tend to stay with the same hardware/software stack for a decade, give or take. Please take the ignorance elsewhere.

Comment: I found this to be a useful question, and pleased the author took the time to publish an answer for the rest of us.

Comment: I’ve just received a Notable Question badge for this, but it remains closed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+1+-+Getting+started says "groovy 1.6 supports JDK 1.4 or greater, for groovy 1.7 onwards, minimum JDK 1.5 is needed"

Comment: check http://www.groovy-lang.org/download.html#requirements seems that the last version which support jdk 1.4 is groovy 1.5 not 1.6.